# Updating elasticsearch index with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I´m trying to figure out how to update my Elasticsearch index. The best I could do is build a scrit where I delete de old Index and then create it again with the new data.

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex

//CALL FILE WITH THIS CONFIGURATION
input {
jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/respuestas_ws"
    jdbc_user => "xxx"
    jdbc_password => "xxx"
    jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.44\mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM xxx"
}
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "myindex"
        document_type => "data"
        hosts => "localhost"
    }
}
```

Is there another way of doing this? The size of my data is small so I´m not that worried about performance at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reindex your index, follow this :https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

Answer (score 0):

If your documents have a unique ID then elasticsearch will just update your documents with the new data. If your table has a my_id column for instance you can use it as the document_id in the output like this:

```
    elasticsearch {
            index => "myindex"
            document_type => "data"
            hosts => "localhost"
            document_id => "%{my_id}"
    }
```